# Scope binding within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I am trying to update the value of a variable in the scope within a directive and then I expect to see the value changed in the html. However, it is not what happens in the example below.

When you press button 1 everything is correct, but when you press button 2 the value is not directly updated, although the counter is increased (you can see it by pressing button 1 again).

js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.plus = function() {
    $scope.count += 1;
  };
})
.directive('dir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      count: '=',
      plus: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        scope.plus();
        scope.count += 1;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h2> {{count}} </h2>
<button ng-click="plus()"> 1 </button>
<button dir count="count" plus="plus()"> 2 </button>
</div>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/k6chmnch/311/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
   scope.$apply(function(){
     scope.count += 1;                
   })
});
```

Comment: Great! It did it! Why is that? In fact, if you modify the scope.counter outside the element.on function it works, why isn't it working inside without the apply?

Comment: You're going to excuse my language, but this is because "Angle" always running "$ apply" on their own policies or events. [See a similiar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556568/angularjs-element-on-callback-and-scope-apply)

Answer (score 0):

The fist thing I see is that you are invoking plus rather than passing in a reference.  Get rid of the parens in the HTML:

```
<button ng-click="plus"> 1 </button>
<button dir count="count" plus="plus"> 2 </button>
```